# Regex to match letters, numbers and some specific characters?

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm trying to match a Django URL bit that can contain:

`_`, `%`, `&`, `+`, `0-9`, `a-z`, `A-Z`, (space)

How can I do it so it is picked up by Django's URL matcher, in form of a parameter?

```
(r'^(?P<chararg>\w+)/IT_NEEDS_TO_BE_HERE/(?P<intarg>\d+)', 'dest')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I played a bit and got this - `[\w\+%_& ]+`.

So `(r'^(?P<chararg>\w+)/IT_NEEDS_TO_BE_HERE/(?P<intarg>\d+)', 'dest')` would become

```
(r'^(?P<chararg>\w+)/(?P<arg>[\w\+%_& ]+)/(?P<intarg>\d+)', 'dest')
```

`\w` matches any word characters and digits.
`\+` mathces +

EDIT: \d is not necessary.

Comment: The `_` here is unnecessary in Python 3 as the \w will match "most characters that can be part of a word in any language, as well as numbers and the underscore."
Or so say the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)
(EDIT: Corrected formatting)

Answer (score 10):

I am not so sure about % char, but regex would be `[_%&+0-9a-zA-Z ]+`

Answer (score 6):

As `\w` means `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, you could use :

```
[%&+ \w]+
```